# Layout constraints not working with view.frame.size.height

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating my UI programmatically and I want to make my `UITextfield` `topAnchor` to be based off the height of its containing `UIView` but it's not working.

My `UITextfield` is inside a `UIView` and I want its `topAnchor` to be 0.15 the height of the `UIView` as such - `containerView.frame.size.height * 0.15` but it seems the value is not picking up. All this is done in a `UIView` subclass and called in the `ViewController`

```
        let containerView: UIView
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(containerView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepTitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 50),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.65)
            ])


        let userTextField: UITextField
        userTextField?.tag = 1
        userTextField?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(userTextField)

        userTextField.setNeedsLayout()
        print("containerView.frame.size.height * 0.15:\(containerView.frame.size.height * 0.15)")
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            (userTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor))!,
            (userTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8))!,
            userTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: containerView.frame.size.height * 0.15),
            userTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            ])
```

I expect the topAnchor of my `UITextField` to appear similar across all devices at 0.15 the height of it container view but what I'm getting is 0

Comment: try calling `layoutIfNeeded()` after `setNeedsLayout()`

Comment: Is the output of the print "0"? If yes the view is allocated with a frame of 0 so you'll have to update your constraint constant every time the view changes frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `NSLayoutConstraint`s and `frame`s.  The frames are *static* and don't update when you use them for the `constant` in a constraint.  So when *Auto Layout* uses the other constraints to update the height of `containerView`, your constraint that looks at `containerView`'s frame height will be based upon the height of the `containerView` at the time of the constraint's creation (which is likely `0`) and not at the time *Auto Layout* uses the constraints to establish the height of `containerView`.

Instead, you want to base the `top` of `userTextField` on the `bottom` of `containerView` with a `multiplier`.  Unfortunately, you can't do that with layout anchors, and you'll have to use `NSLayoutContraint` to create it:

Replace:

```
userTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor,
    constant: containerView.frame.size.height * 0.15)
```

with:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: userTextField, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
    toItem: containerView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 0.15, constant: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it with `self` not `container` as container's height is not  yet  calculated

```
userTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor,  
     constant: self.frame.size.height * 0.15 * 0.65 )
```

Given that the height of container = 0.65 * from self here

```
self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.65
```

Comment: The `self.frame.size.height` is the height of `view` at the time this constraint is created, not its height at the time the constraint is used. The height of `view` could change on different devices, or in the case of rotation.  Mixing NSLayoutConstraints and frames is a bad idea.