# How to apply constraints with width/height in Autolayout if they are 0 in init()?

Tags: swift, autolayout, interface-builder

I am struggling to apply the following constraints:

```
documentTypeCircle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleContentScrollView.topAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.03).isActive = true
documentStepTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: documentTypeCircle.bottomAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.05).isActive = true
documentStepTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: self.frame.width * 0.05).isActive = true
documentStepTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width * 0.73).isActive = true
uploadImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: documentStepTableView.bottomAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.05).isActive = true
```

I need to access self.frame.width, but the value is 0.

I add this view in loadView() of ViewController, because it is recommended approach:

```
 override func loadView() {
    self.view = CustomView(frame: .zero)
 }
```

How can I make sure, that self.frame.width **provides width of whole view**, instead of returning 0?
If I move constraints logic to layoutSubviews() it works correctly, however **constraints are created multiple times** and this seems like unclean solution:

```
override open func layoutSubviews() {
documentTypeCircle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleContentScrollView.topAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.03).isActive = true
documentStepTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: documentTypeCircle.bottomAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.05).isActive = true
documentStepTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: self.frame.width * 0.05).isActive = true
documentStepTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width * 0.73).isActive = true
uploadImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: documentStepTableView.bottomAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.05).isActive = true
```

}

If however I instantiated view with UIScreen.main.bounds instead of .zero it worked well even in init() of customView. However, I confused why it is such a case that custom view is drawn correctly with **UIScreen.main.bounds instead of .zero**. Shouldn't autolayout handle this even with .zero?

**EDIT**

I found [recommended approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020632/layout-constraints-not-working-with-view-frame-size-height/56021292#56021292), but can't make it work for our case. New layout does not look like an old one and all constraints seem to be all over the place

My new constraints and commented old ones with frames:

```
//documentTypeCircle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleContentScrollView.topAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.03).isActive = true

      NSLayoutConstraint(item: documentTypeCircle, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: middleContentScrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 0.03, constant: 0).isActive = true

//documentStepTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: documentTypeCircle.bottomAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.05).isActive = true

      NSLayoutConstraint(item: documentStepTitle, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: documentTypeCircle, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0).isActive = true

//documentStepTableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: self.frame.width * 0.05).isActive = true

      NSLayoutConstraint(item: documentStepTableView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0).isActive = true

//documentStepTableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width * 0.73).isActive = true

      NSLayoutConstraint(item: documentStepTableView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.73, constant: 0).isActive = true


//uploadImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: documentStepTableView.bottomAnchor, constant: self.frame.height * 0.05).isActive = true
      NSLayoutConstraint(item: uploadImageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
      toItem: documentStepTableView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 0.05, constant: 0).isActive = true
Perhaps I am mixing anchor with NSLayoutConstraint, however I feel like it is impossible to achieve same layout behaviour with auto layout, without using frames.
```

Comment: Are you sure you want your constraints to have a constant of `self.frame.height * 0.03`? What if `self.frame.height` changes? Do you want the constraint's constant to stay the same, rather than to use the new `self.frame.height`?

Comment: @Sweeper I don't change constraints in any way. I need to draw whole UI in the beginning and don't change it. The problem is that if I pass .zero, then my scroll view is not visible, because I can't calculate constraints correctly. If I pass UIScreen.main.bounds I can calculate, but I am not sure if it is correct approach, because it is suggested to pass .zero if you use autolayout.

Perhaps I need to call layoutIfNeeded() before setting my constraints?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you try to set your constraints in loadView() rated to your frame, frame is 0 because all frames haven't initialized yet, and they will only in layoutSubviews()

Try to not sue frames, its more difficult to find the solution in this way, but better to use regular constraints, they will set in correct time

For better understanding: https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5

Comment: I am using regular constraints. I am just setting constant of constraint related to width

Comment: Yes, just use different values, not related to frame/bounds 
Or you can set the area of your constraint: 
set first one greaterThanOrEqual and the second one lessOrEqual to give your constraints space

Comment: Or you can just use UIScreen.main.bounds to get screen width

Comment: Isn't UIScreen.main.bounds not dynamic in a way, that it will not work well with autolayout? Or I can pass UIScreen.main.bounds instead of .zero and it will be ok?

Comment: Its depend which solution you need

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? :)

Comment: I mean. If you want to get size of your screen, its fine if you will use UIScreen.main.bounds instead your self.view.bounds. But if you set your constraints depend on another views, you have to use static constraints value. Also apple provide more flexible layout if you use aspectRatio, to follow right sides aspects

Comment: Thanks. What about using .zero vs UIScreen.main.bounds. I managed to change my constraints to these : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56021292/9163128 and now I can pass .zero. So the answer from that question is correct, yes?

Comment: Yes, this answer correct, its not a good cod style to mix frame + constraints. Thats why better to use aspect ratio and relating one side by another

Comment: I tried that approach and it did not worked. It seems that it is not possible to achieve same layout behaviour without using frames. Can you look at my edited answer?

Comment: self.view = CustomView(frame: .zero) do nothing in your case, because view didn't initialized yet. Just try to play with aspect ratio and multiplying and it will work. 

I don't know your case, but if its fine for you, and its necessary, just use UIScreen.main.bounds if you need width of all screens (it works because screen bounds initialized int didFinishLaunchWithOptions in your appDelegate)

Answer (score 0):

UIScreen.main.bounds gives you the bounds of the screen, whereas .zero simply initialize your view with CGRect(0, 0, 0 ,0) which is a rectangle of height 0 width 0 at coordinate 0,0, which will then in turn give you a width of 0 of course. I’m not clear about what you are struggling with, if you just want a reference for the width of the whole screen, I believe you can still use UIScreen.main.bounds.width. Btw, I normally set my constraints in viewDidLoad, pretty sure many people do the same.

Comment: It is strange :( Recommended way is to use loadView, by apple documentation as well if your view is written in code

Comment: ViewDidLoad didn't know about frames yet, use viewDidAppear or (apple recommend) layoutSubviews